# Show $\mu \ge x (1 - F(x))$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $x$ be a random variable distributed according to a CDF $F$, which is atomless and differentiable. The support is $[0,1]$. I want to show that $\mu \ge x (1 - F(x)), \forall x\in [0,1]$, where $\mu = \int_0^1 xdF(x)$. I can verify this for a specific form of distribution, say uniform, but I am not sure how to show this for general $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mu=\int_0^{1} tdF(t) \geq \int_x^{1} tdF(t) \geq \int_x^{1} xdF(t)=x\int_x^{1}dF(t)=x(1-F(x)$.